# Jquery and Vanilla javascript return different element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this element

```
<li @click="menuActivator"><a><div><i class="fas fa-tasks"></i> Pending</div></a></li>
```

which when clicked will just console the element which element execute the event but upon analyzing jquery and vanilla javascript returns different result

Jquery result: returns the whole `li` element

```
$('#sidebar>ul>li').on('click',function(){
    console.log($(this))
})
```

on the otherhand
Vanilla Javascript: return the `div` element

```
menuActivator:function(event){
  console.log(event.target)
}
```

I want to get exactly which element triggered the event which should be the `li` using vanilla javscript

Comment: Not sure what framework that is, but in jQuery you're logging `this` - try doing the same in `menuActivator`

Comment: `@click="menuActivator"` and `menuActivator:function` aren't "vanilla" javascript - what other library/framework are you using?

Comment: A click event bubbles up through the tree. Depending on where exactly you click, and whether elements have padding, you'll get the `<i>`, the `<div>`, the `<a>` or the `<li>`.

Comment: `event.target` is where the click event occurred and `this` is where the event handler is assigned - the event bubbles/propagates up to parent elements if it's not handled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `currentTarget` instead of `target`.